# NFL rule changes to balance defense more, but do not reduce player safety

Tags: nfl

This might get flagged as an opinion question, but I hope not. I think its interesting. Offensive numbers started to rise in the early 1980s. According to wikipedia, the 1978 season had a series of rule changes to increase scoring. I think there have been alot of rule changes over the last 30+ years to improve offense. I do not think most of them were done to help player safety. Are their rules changes that the NFL could make to balance the game more that would not make the game less safe? I don't think the NFL wants to because offense generally brings more ratings. I was thinking of a few. I hope this question is ok.

1. offensive pass interference includes loss of down. The penalties for defensive pass interference are so much worse.
2. Defenders can now touch players up to 10 yards down field instead of 5 (this dates to the 1978 rule changes) possibly unless that defender is inside the opponents 20 yard line. (not alot of space when you are near the goal line). This might be really complex to enforce...
3. I think pass interference rules have changed many times over the years. I am wondering if you can make things in a little (should be phased in ) more lenient on defenders.

any other ideas?

Comment: I think this is pure speculation, which isn't what we do here.

Comment: If you believe you will get flagged, it is encouraged to discuss your prospective question in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse), and we will help you.